# Limiting records in a model action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, limit

How do I limit the number of records that I am outputting with the following code to only 3 records:

User.rb

```
  def workouts_on_which_i_commented
    comments.map{|x|x.workout}.uniq
  end

  def comment_stream
   workouts_on_which_i_commented.map do |w|
     w.comments
   end.flatten.sort{|x,y| y.created_at <=> x.created_at}
 end
```

html.erb file

```
<% current_user.comment_stream.each do |comment| %>
    ...
<% end %>
```

UPDATE:

I'm using Rails 2.3.9

Comment: My answer should work...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rails 3:

```
def workouts_on_which_i_commented
  comments.limit(3).map{|x|x.workout}.uniq
end
```

Rails < 3:

Since `comments` is an `Array` of `Comment` objects, you can simply `slice` it:

```
def workouts_on_which_i_commented
  comments[0..2].map{|x|x.workout}.uniq
end
```

Comment: I get an error here. I might should have mentioned that I am using Rails 2.3.9. Here is the error: `undefined method `limit' for #<Class:0x10449a408>`.

Comment: @bgadoci Looks like you're not using Rails 3 then.

Comment: Ha, we commented at the same time.

Comment: The only problem I see here is that changing `comments` to `Comment.find...` returns all comments instead of just comments from workouts that current_user commented on. Make sense?

Comment: @bgadoci Yes, hang on I'm finding a solution.

Comment: My problem with your solution is you get all the data first then limits it. You should instead limit the query.

Comment: @Mike Yeah, that's true, but a) the query is only executed once. and b) it already has all of the criteria, so instead of running another query, why not use the already cached result set?

Comment: @jacob I'm saying he should limit the first query. Instead of getting everything get what he needs. If he's getting stuff in anticipation of what he might want then that's bad code. If that's so he needs rethink what he's doing and refactor to be more efficient and only do the work needed.

Comment: One follow up question here: Any idea how I would eliminate current_user comments from this stream? See my new question about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4560109/eliminating-current-user-activity-from-records-being-returned-through-a-complex-a

Answer (score 1):

whatever `comments` is in your `workouts_on_which_i_commented`, could be `Comment.all(:order => 'created_at DESC', :limit => 3)`

There is some fancy rails 3 syntax too, but this is good for either.

Or if this method is in a model, you can just do `comments(:order => 'created_at DESC', :limit => 3)` instead of what was described in my first sentence.