# Eliminating current_user activity from records being returned through a complex association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

I have built a Ruby on Rails application (Rails 2.3.9) that allows users to track workouts. After a workout is created other users can comment on that workout. I am now working on the `Dashboard` index view to display recent activity.

In this particular section I am trying to display comments from all on workouts that `current_user` has commented on. I am successfully pulling those comments, ordering them, and limiting the output through the below code.

I am now trying to **exclude** comments from current user. Here is the code:

/views/dashboard/index.html.erb

```
  <% unless current_user.comment_stream.blank? %>
      <h3>Recent Comments from WODs you commented on</h3>
        <% current_user.comment_stream[0,10].each do |comment| %>
          <p>
             Comment from <%= link_to (comment.user.username), comment.user %> 
             <%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %> ago on Workout: 
             <%= link_to (comment.workout.title), comment.workout %>
          </p>
        <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

User.rb

```
  def workouts_on_which_i_commented
    comments.map{|x|x.workout}.uniq
  end

  def comment_stream
   workouts_on_which_i_commented.map do |w|
     w.comments
   end.flatten.sort{|x,y| y.created_at <=> x.created_at}
  end
```

**Example of Problem**:

Here is an example of what happens with this code:

User A creates a workout and User B comments on it. Then User C and User D also comment on User A's workout. In User B's dashboard view, I want him to see comments from User C and User D in the activity stream...but I don't want him to see his own comments.

I could simply use a `<% unless comment.user_id == current_user.id %>` but that messes up the number of records being displayed as those are fished prior to the exclusion line.

Answer (score 0):

In comment_stream, you can add filter out the comments you posted

```
def comment_stream
  workouts_on_which_i_commented.map do |w|
    w.comments
  end.flatten.reject{|c| c.user_id == current_user.id}.sort{|x,y| y.created_at <=> x.created_at}
end
```

Comment: For some reason this now throws an error from my view code `undefined local variable or method `current_user' for #<User:0x10c6c4c30>` and is coming from this line `<% unless current_user.comment_stream.blank? %>`. Any ideas?

Comment: @bgadoci: Are you using Authlogic? If so, make sure you are logged in.

Comment: I am using Authlogic and I am logged in.